# Kohana modules -path .htaccess protection and media -files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, module, kohana

In `Kohana` there's `modules` -path protection in `.htaccess`

```
# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
```

How could I allow paths like:

`http://localhost/modules/mymodule/media/js/myjavascript.js`

I would like to include javascript and other media files to my module and still protect other module files like `.php`

I could allow whole `modules` -path, but then all `.php` -files would be listed too.

```
# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
```

Sure there is basic PHP -protection, but I still won't want that anyone could list my `modules` -path.

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to serve those files using a media controller. So a user could request "js/script.js" and Kohana would load the first file it finds using the cascading file structure. There's a good media controller that comes with Kohana, it's in the Userguide module:

[Line 247 of classes/controller/userguide.php](https://github.com/kohana/userguide/blob/3.1%2Fmaster/classes/controller/userguide.php#L247)

```
public function action_media()
{
    // Get the file path from the request
    $file = $this->request->param('file');

    // Find the file extension
    $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Remove the extension from the filename
    $file = substr($file, 0, -(strlen($ext) + 1));

    if ($file = Kohana::find_file('media/guide', $file, $ext))
    {
        // Check if the browser sent an "if-none-match: <etag>" header, and tell if the file hasn't changed
        $this->response->check_cache(sha1($this->request->uri()).filemtime($file), $this->request);

        // Send the file content as the response
        $this->response->body(file_get_contents($file));

        // Set the proper headers to allow caching
        $this->response->headers('content-type',  File::mime_by_ext($ext));
        $this->response->headers('last-modified', date('r', filemtime($file)));
    }
    else
    {
        // Return a 404 status
        $this->response->status(404);
    }
}
```

This wont be the fastest solution, but if you correctly set the response headers the files should be cached on the client browser.

Answer (score 1):

Solution, add this RewriteCond just before RewriteRule

```
# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*/)*(application|application/cache|modules/[^/]*)/media/.*$
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
```